# Video conference Android phone to computer

Tags: video-calling

Can I video talk from my Android Motorola Droid to my computer.  If so, how?
Can I video talk from my Android Motorola Droid to someone else's computer? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried Skype? There's an Android app available.

Comment: Or Google Hangouts. Or Oovoo. Or any of a number of video chat services.

Comment: One thing that is worthy to mention - iirc, Gingerbread *did* not have capability to use front-facing video camera if present on the device!

Comment: OP: What version of Android are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Android 2.3.4 or higher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#API_level_10.2C_Android_2.3.3-2.3.7_Gingerbread) you are able to video chat with GTalk.

Even better, Google Hangouts allows you to perform one to many video chats.

Comment: Thought GB did not have capability to use front-facing camera?

Comment: Yes the API interface came later. But 2.3.4 does support video calling with GTalk (and IIRC with the front facing camera).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, *maybe* possible!

This will depend solely on the two crucial elements

- if there's a front facing camera on the handset, and that is running Skype, then yes.
- Stable Wifi internet connection
- The account on the Desktop PC, with Skype, shall be called (*for illustrative purpose in explaining how it works*) 'Bob'
- The account on the handset, with Skype, shall be called 'Alice'

What you need to do is, with your Desktop PC, log on to Skype using 'Bob'. Now, 'Bob' must have 'Alice' added as their contact..

From the handset, log into Skype using 'Alice', and that account **also** must have 'Bob' added as their contact.

Then just interact on Skype on handset, logged in as 'Alice', talking to 'Bob' which is on the desktop PC.

Answer (score -2):

Please check out [zoom.us](http://zoom.us). Android version is still in [beta](https://support.zoom.us/entries/21892952-will-zoom-us-be-coming-out-for-android).

Comment: Can you provide more detail about this than a link?  If the URL changes this answer won't be useful.